# Automating Logins with Perl

Tags: perl, web, https, www-mechanize

I am trying to write a script which logs into my Intex account.  For some reason I can't get past the login screen.  I know the page is https and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in accounting for this security.  At the end of the script, as a test, I try to launch the page in chrome.  This just leads me back to the login screen.  Thank you for your help.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' );
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());

my $url = 'https://www.intex.com/main/login.php';
$mech->get( $url );

my $pass = 'example';

$mech->set_visible( $pass);
$mech->click;

#this is a test to see whether the next output is wrong
print $mech->text(); 

my $link = mech->uri();
system ('start chrome '.$link);
```

I'm now using www::mechanize::firefox and having trouble with upload forms.  Can anyone tell me how I would use that module to submit a file to a form like this?

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

edit::I need to click a button like this...

```
<B><FONT SIZE=2>Then click...</FONT></B><A HREF="Javascript:CheckPortfolioUpload('Portfolio - Select Portfolio - Upload ? Go ~ Results')"><IMG NAME=GoBtn SRC=/images/button/GreenGo.gif BORDER=0 TITLE='Upload'  CLASS=Clickable></IMG></A>
</TABLE>
```

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You aren't passing any cookies or anything to chrome, just a link. So your chrome session certainly won't be logged in.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the comment.  I really appreciate the help.  That makes sense about the cookies, but it looks like from the $mech->text() that I never got past the login page anyway.  Regardless,  how do I pass the cookies to chrome?

Comment: It looks like a javascript/ajax login, which $mech clicking won't accomplish anything as it doesn't run javascript. If you are going to be opening a browser window anyway, I would suggest using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox which will use an actual firefox browser, javascript engine and all.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response.  I'll give that a try and repost later in the day.

Comment: Hey ugexe,I wanted to thank you for your help.  I'm figuring out the remainder of my project with the firefox extension and your suggested module.